# Spring session and websockets: session not stored in session repository

Tags: java, spring, session, spring-websocket, spring-session

I have an application with Spring Session and Spring Websockets. I use websocket handshake interceptor to set properties to websocket session

```java
public class WebsocketHandshakeInterceptor implements HandshakeInterceptor {


    @Override
    public boolean beforeHandshake(ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response,
                                   WebSocketHandler wsHandler, Map<String, Object> attributes) throws Exception {
        if (request instanceof ServletServerHttpRequest) {
            ServletServerHttpRequest servletRequest = (ServletServerHttpRequest) request;
            HttpSession session = servletRequest.getServletRequest().getSession(true);
            if (session != null) {
                attributes.put(ApplicationConstants.HTTP_SESSION_ID_KEY, session.getId());
                attributes.put(ApplicationConstants.HTTP_SESSION_KEY, session);
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterHandshake(ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response,
                               WebSocketHandler wsHandler, Exception ex) {
    }
}
```

Then I catch `SessionConnectEvent`. Event contais needed information (http session and session id). But the session is `null` in `sessionRepository`

```
@Component
public class WebSocketListener implements ApplicationListener<SessionConnectEvent> {

@Autowired
private MapSessionRepository sessionManager;

@Override
public void onApplicationEvent(SessionConnectEvent event) {
    String httpSessionId
            = event.getWebSocketSession().getAttributes().get(ApplicationConstants.HTTP_SESSION_ID_KEY).toString();
    sessionManager.getSession(httpSessionId); //returns null
}
}
```

It returns `null` with the first call, if I try to reconnect, it returns valid session. Can you show me my error? Thanks.

Comment: What is the intended purpose of your `WebsocketHandshakeInterceptor`? Spring Session provides its own `SessionRepositoryMessageInterceptor` which ensures that the Session is added to the WebSocket properties to enable updating the last accessed time. See [the docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/1.2.1.RELEASE/reference/html5/#websocket-usage) and [the implementation](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/blob/master/spring-session/src/main/java/org/springframework/session/web/socket/server/SessionRepositoryMessageInterceptor.java#L134-L144).